# Как определить выбранный элемент из списка в Tkinter.ListBox?

Tags: python, tkinter

При выборе элемента из списка `Listbox (lis) - lis.bind("Button-1>",choose)` выполняется процедура

```
 def choose(vbr):
        choose=lis.curselection()
        print choose
```

Когда выбираю, к примеру, 1-й элемент выводится - ('0',), нельзя ли как-то получить только номер выбранной строки?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, вы имеете в виду `lis[0]` или `int(lis[0])`

Из John W. Shipman "Tkinter 8.4 reference: a GUI for Python":

> .curselection()
>
> *Returns a tuple containing the line numbers of the selected element or elements, counting from 0.
> If nothing is selected, returns an empty tuple.*

Так что вы можете увеличить каждый из элементов последовательности на 1.
Что нибудь типа `choose = lis.curselection()[0]+1` или `choose = map(lambda x:x+1, lis.curselection())`. Правда map возвращает список, если это имеет значение.

Comment: При выполнении  

def choose(vbr):
    choose=lis.curselection()[0]
    print choose
Выдает ошибку:

choose=lis.curselection()[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: А у Вас какой-нибудь элемент выбран?
попробуйте `choose=lis.curselection()
print choose
choose=choose[0]
print choose`
если получите то, что было в вопросе (выбран первый элемент), `choose[0]` должен дать '0'

Comment: Точно, как по умолчанию поставить 0-й элемент как выбранный?

Comment: Движением мыша и нажатием на кнопку. Если программно, то: .selection_set ( first, last=None )
Selects all of the lines between indices first and last, inclusive. If the second argument is omitted,
selects the line with index first.
т.е. lis.selection_set(0) (1-я строка), lis.selection_set('END') -- последняя, и т.д. (согласно руководству)